# How close are we to eternal consciousness?

Tags: science-based, biology, brain

A common trope in cyber punkish sci-fi is the ability to upload a human mind to some storage device or AI. This of course grants practical immortality but it is also the main hurdle for tropes like teleportation, cloning etc.

So my question is: how close are we to being able to make restorable backups of a human brain? What scientific or engineering break throughs are required?

For the sake of this question, the goal is:

- To transfer the complete memories, feelings and "consciousness" (whatever that is) of a human being to an external storage device (electronic or biological) of some kind.
- To be able to interact with the back up, directly or after a "restore" to another human body.
- It should be impossible to tell original and back up apart without seeing their physical form.

The question has been asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-close-are-we-to-creating-a-backup-of-the-data-contained-in-a-human-brain) but without any detailed answers.

I'm tagging this "Science-based", but any hard-science answers are preferred.

Comment: I would argue we are much closer to make this happen biologically = arbitrary long life. That doesn't mean we are anywhere close to either. I also believe this question gets asked here once a month

Comment: Ps: let me explain: we already have the machine and the person in there. I always wonder why one would first construct a machine and then figure out how to upload if one can avoid those steps. That's like trying to make a cake by first constricting a fusion reactor to generate heat

Comment: @Raditz_35 I suppose future tech could go either way, but even if we could prolong the life span of human brain (and body) that would still not protect an individual mind from catastrophic failure. (like a bullet to the head). If this you feel this is a duplicate, please post some links and VTC. I did not find the same question with a quick search, nor do I recall one, but that might just be poor search skills.

Comment: I'm not capable of copying links right now. Btw the answer in tjose threads is always: absolutely no chance in the foreseeable future. Don't think any research is devoted to this either. As I stated you are not asking for the next step but want to skip 10 steps at once

Comment: This is probably best read there is about our current technology in this area: https://waitbutwhy.com/2017/04/neuralink.html

Comment: 31 years 8 months, 13 days and 11 hours 41 minutes 17 seconds. (+- 6 seconds)

Comment: It's been done on flatworms already, just human brains have a billion times more neurons. Assuming capability doubles every year (optimistic, but a range of biotech like gene sequencing follows similar trends) then we are 30 years away. So probably 25 to 40 years.

Comment: Making a "backup" seems pointless.  YOU still die, the restored entity is a different person that just happens to have your memories.

Comment: @jamesqf Whats the difference between 2 identical people with the same memories?

Comment: @A.C.A.C. Think of it this way.  Let's say we upload your brain into a clone: now there are two identical "you"s side-by-side, with the same memories.  Now let's say I point a gun at the original you, and threaten to pull the trigger.  If the original you dies, and the second you is still around, the consciousness of the original you is gone to whatever you believe in as a post-death experience while the consciousness of the second you is still alive.  That's the difference.

Comment: @Ghotir But there is not physical difference. Unless you think the original is special in that case then the one that dies doesn't matter. There is nothing really special about have 2 instance of the same person that diverge once the cloning happens and having 1 die with the other surviving would mean the person up to that point survives. Everything else would just be superstition.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. To others, it wouldn't matter: it's the same body with the same memories and personality.  With that said, it would *very* much matter to me if I were the one about to be shot!  Knowing there's another "me" out there doesn't help: there's a biological imperative to survive.  (To anyone other than me, it might not make any difference... but to the me about to be killed, it's literally a life-or-death difference.)

Comment: @Ghotir Yes, if you move the timeline past the instant that there are 2 of you, then there would be 2 different people because they are no longer the same person, the simple experience of you existing past separation would mean the 2 of you will have different memories. Now if you were both sync'ed with the cloud, you would know to let one of you die and accept that the other you will live on. Local copies that aren't backed up loses information when deleted but if both version are kept the same then no information is lost.

Comment: I think the bigger point he's trying to make here is that the subjective experience of the one being destroyed is still one of imminent destruction. I'm rather attached to the continuity of my existence, and it's not much comfort to know there's someone else out there who can replace me, father my children, love my wife, etc. without really mourning the loss of me, even though I'm gone.

Comment: @jamesqf The value of a backup might not be for the person being backed up. I might write a story where (lets say) the head of a terrorist org is executed, but not before his mind is backed up. (We want him dead, but we also want to know his future plans)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are still far away from being able to correctly interpret a neural system and to be able to simulate that on a computer of some kind.

We have a kind of mixed situation about our understanding of brain (and nervous system in general) physiology; I will try to sketch what I understand of "State of the Art".

- We have a fairly good understanding of neuron workings, down to molecular level, at least for local interactions.
- We have several "models" that capture (at different levels of precision) neuron *functionality*, abstracting it completely from actual chemical processes powering it. These "models" are powerful and useful enough to be used in real-life A.I.s solving computationally "hard" problems (e.g.: weather forecasts).
- We are not sure we have understood all implications of "systemic" neurotransmitters (the ones in the blood stream).
- Systemic neurotransmitters seem to play a key role in "reward system" and thus on all network training and memorization.
- We have a general map of connections between neurons both in brain and in Spinal chord.
- We have no *detailed* connection map.
- There is still no consensus if current neuron *models* actually contain enough information to faithfully replicate a Natural Neuron Network functionality in a Simulated Neuron Network.
- We have little to no understanding of process leading to formation of new synapses (neuron connections).
- We have little to no understanding of processes leading to modification of synapses.
- The above two points mean we are really far from having a sensible breakthrough on learning and memorization processes.
- A detailed mapping of neuron interconnection is impossible right now, but is thinkable in a relatively near future.
- Compute a map of "weight" connection for each neuron is a problem several orders of magnitude more complex, but still theoretically doable.
- As said there is no consensus about if and, eventually, how much these parameters unequivocally characterize the whole network.
- Assuming all this data actually define enough the brain there is the problem to fully simulate this NNN with a suitable SNN (computationally intractable, to date, essentially due to the high degree of parallelism needed).
- If and when the above problems are solved it's possible to have a simulated conscience responding (given the necessary "peripherals") "as if" the original human was still alive. A few problems would remain:

  - as said there's still not consensus if the model I'm outlining captures enough of neuron complexity to replicate faithfully behavior.
  - these models completely ignore "systemic" influences.
  - these models do not include any part of some proposed (and undemonstrated) "local" interneuron "resonances".
  - in any case it would be a conscience "frozen", with no way to learn anything "long term" (short term memories would be possible).
- There are studies on how to model neuron interaction at a higher level, but AFAIK they are not applicable for "backup" purposes.

I see *no* way to restore any kind of "backup" unto a biologic brain, in *any* foreseeable future, as:

- We have no understanding of how to grow neurons with specific connection pattern (neurons grow new connections in the learning process, reaching several *hundred thousand* connection for a single neuron)
- We have very small chance to "restore" behavior of even a *single* neuron because signal sensitivity is encoded in membrane artifacts which will be very hard to duplicate.
- We need to do the above on almost a *hundred billions* neurons (not counting sympathetic system, spinal chord and the myriad nerve ganglia we have almost anywhere; *note: recent studies indicate these are **not** irrelevant to our behavior*).
- Some of the "global" states of the brain are controlled by "systemic" neurotransmitters floating in the blood stream. At least some of these are generated by systems very far from the brain (cardiac ganglia, adrenal glands, intestine, etc.).

Comment: A biological restore is not neccessary per this question. A self conscious AI with the full memories and personality of an original human is sufficient.

Comment: @Guran: OP explicitly states "after a "restore" to another human body".

Comment: I am the OP ;) and the question is "_directly, or_ after a restore.

Comment: @Guran: oops, I missed that. I will update my answer to include current "State of Arts" about the "functional backup" which, I can tell you is *not* very near, but neither deemed "impossible". It will take some time ;)

Comment: Congrats, those bullet points made yours the preferred answer, though many are similar.

Answer (score 25):

We are really far, far away.

First of all, we still don't know how memories, feeling and consciousness are coded in our brain. We have some ideas on which brain areas are devoted to certain tasks (sort of black box model), but we still lack the finer detail. If we make the (somehow poor) analogy with a computer, we know which is the RAM, the ROM and which the GPU, but we have no clue on how data are processed and stored there. Now, imagine how ridiculous  would somebody appear approaching a hard disk with just paper and pen to copy its content, and you have a hint of our standpoint when it comes to "copying brains".

The first breakthrough would then be to understand this fine level detail. By knowing how the information is coded, we can read it (continuing with the computer analogy, once we know that bits are coded with a magnetic field on the substrate, we can arrange a magnetic head to read it). Once this is known, we can then move on to try to replicate it. Once we are able to replicate it, copying and pasting is possible.

Comment: Plus we'd have to figure out how to read the state of a brain, and (still more difficult) how to *write* one.

Comment: In other words, there are substantial scientific breakthroughs required (figure out how a "consciousness" is represented in physical form) before we can even begin to tackle the engineering challenges (how to read and store a state of mind).

This answer could be improved by some actual reference to what our current knowledge is.

Comment: @Guran: The point he is making is that our "current knowledge" is non-existent. We can recognize the hardware, but we have absolutely no idea of how data is processed within it.

Comment: ...which is quite fascinating, since such tech generally comes before interstellar travel in most sci-fi. (in my mind at least)

Comment: @Guran From my experience, "completely obfuscating mortality" is not shown or implied to have happened at all in most Sci-Fi. Creating an AI out of a human mind isn't that uncommon, but I wouldn't call it the norm and it I don't think I've seen the process be reversible with any kind of frequency

Comment: We can already decode  the brain's activity to a point though, for an example see: https://www.technologyreview.com/s/604332/mind-reading-algorithms-reconstruct-what-youre-seeing-using-brain-scan-data/ where they used AI to read, from brain activity, what the user was seeing.

Comment: We are also really far far away from interstellar travel, so there is no inconsistency there :).

Comment: Paper and pen, a magnifying glass and a screwdriver. Whilst the drive is running.

Comment: It could be "worse" than that. The analogy of a computer is a common one nowadays, but is probably part of the reason we can't even understand the problem yet. Good read on the topic: https://aeon.co/essays/your-brain-does-not-process-information-and-it-is-not-a-computer

Comment: I will quibble with the word eternal.  I don't think we can build anything that will survive even a significant fraction of the time remaining until the universe's heat death, let alone the heat death itself.

Comment: I think you're underselling current capabilities a bit.  We *are* decoding complex thoughts in living people presently.  https://cacm.acm.org/news/219023-cmu-scientists-harness-mind-reading-technology-to-decode-complex-thoughts/fulltext  The astonishing-to-me result is that the activation patterns were largely independent of subject.

Comment: @EricTowers You should expand that into an answer.

Comment: @EricTowers, it the same way we can detect the EM noise of a screen and reconstruct what's being displayed on that screen. This doesn't make us closer to understand how the computer connected to that screen is working.

Comment: The least unrealistic scenario for uploading not being that far is that somehow we figure out how to build a non-human-like machine superintelligence, trigger the Singularity, and the machine figures out how to simulate humans. (One could argue that the current technology is pretty close to what's needed for machine superintelligence, given that we already have tooling of comparable power to the human brain, and AIs start to be uncannily good and generally exceed everyone's expectations. It's a weak argument IMO, but not a completely ridiculous one.)

Comment: Alternatively, we might already live in a simulation, in which case all it takes is a configuration change.

Comment: @L.Dutch : No.  "detect the EM noise of a screen ... displayed on that screen" would be analogous to determining mental states from observations of affect states.  We are already watching which regions of the CPU are activating and from that determining details of the computation in progress.  We know the medium scale dataflow map in the grey matter.  http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.0060159  This means we know the busses and functional unit connection topology.  Your information seems to stop some time in the '90s.

Answer (score 7):

Saying "very far away" may be an understatement.

First of all, we do not have the faintest idea of how the brain works at all, nor a good way of even looking at it.
This profound non-understanding coupled with very modest means to even look at what's going on has lead to ill-advised beliefs such as we're only using 10% of our brain.

There's EEG, which is basically a couple of wiggly lines in which scientists try to find patterns, but if you're being honest it's close to reading tea leaves. The problem is that what the EEG shows is a summation of interfering microscopic impulses along a multitude of vectors, under the (probably wrong) assumption/simplification that cranial structures and/or skin conductivity go exactly the way you think and do not influence the outcome. Put differently, you're looking at some pretty patterns, but there's no way you can truthfully make too much of it in a sense of "read mind" or even "copy a personality". But even assuming you could read someone's mind that way, this would likely still not let you extract knowledge that isn't being accessed or copy a personality from those electric impulses.

There's the UCSD experiment where probands (although the researchers were in my opinion cheating because all they really measured was the brain's response to a flicker pattern that probands looked at!) managed to "dial" numbers on a cell phone by means of thought patterns. Well, awesome. The brain reacts to external stimuli, that's big news. Now tell me how to upload your mind to your cellphone.

And there's MRI, which gives even prettier patterns than EEG, in color and in 3D. You can show that certain areas of the brain light up when certain things are done or when certain external stimuli appear. While this is impressive, it's approximately the same thing Mengele did 70 years earlier, only less invasive, and at slightly higher resolution.
From "we see these areas light up" to "copy a personality" it's approximately like having discovered that things that you drop fall to the ground and a manned mission to Mars.

We do not know exactly *how* the brain stores (or processes) information. Yes, we do have some educated guesses, but we don't really know exactly. When looking at not only what a simple honey bee is capable of *remembering*, but also how capable it is at path planning and rather non-trivial mechanical tasks, I'm stunned how the hell nature manages to fit all that into a brain the size of a needle pin. How large is *your* brain again? Good luck decoding that.

We do not even know how much information a human brain can store, but we *do know* that the amount is huge, and we know that information is stored in a non-obvious way which one could consider a kind of "interlinked lossy compression with forward and backward error correction". Something like that. Memories are not just data, they are data that has been filtered, weighted and validated, and connected to other, sometimes unrelated data in a non-obvious way, with massive holes that are filled from other data, or sometimes interpolated with what seems plausible to the brain, and with no way of telling a difference (guess why witnesses are such a pain in the ass). So far, we cannot even remotely guess how this works at all. We can only tell it must be something the like from observing what people remember (and sometimes what they *think* they remember). Some personality-defining memories/abilities (let's say playing an instrument) are in addition supported by dedicated hardware (if you want to call the cerebellum that). Which, of course, you would need to somehow copy too.

We don't know whether *personality* has anything to do with stored information either, or where personality comes from, for that matter. Is it defined by your experience? Genetic? Given by God? Hardwired by your dendrites? Stored chemically? We have no idea. We can only tell from observation, with reasonable certitude, that it's *probably not* one of the previously mentioned things alone.
Experiments that might give an answer would take decades and would be highly unethical to the point of being forbidding (e.g. raise clones in different environments, observe them for 20-25 years, then cut their brains to slices).

If we knew all of the above, we still wouldn't know how to map all of this to a digital format that a computer can store, let alone build a computer large enough to do the job, or how to "transfer back" the mind, once copied and stored. While it might, in principle, be feasible one day to copy the "data" from the human via some "scan thingie", the brain simply isn't built to receive a new mind like this. There's no "input" plug of sorts.

Comment: Mapping to a digital format is not a problem. We can currently map all the information we have. The question could be the available memory, but if we have some big cloud like Google, than it can be much bigger than the information that a brain has.

Comment: @keiv.fly: Doubtful. While for example synapses obviously operate on quantifiable information (molecules) they are by all practical means fuzzy analog devices. Sure, in theory you can store the type of every molecule in a human body, if only given enough memory. But that's not realistic. At around 200g/mol on the average for neurotransmitters, if each molecule took but a single bit of storage, that'd already be 2^80 bytes for a snapshot of one brain's synapses... ugh... if memory capacity doesn't bite you, then bandwidth...

Answer (score 5):

Like others have said already, this is still in the not-forseable future. The main reason is very simple: We have no clue how consciousness actually works.

Science has made a lot of progress explaining the most basic building blocks of nerves and brains. We have also accumulated a lot of knowledge of finer details, but here already our understand of **how** this actually happens is beginning to be vague. For example, object recognition and object persistence in visual perception. We know a lot about it, and another lot is under active research because we haven't figured it out yet. And that's a low-level building block of the entire visual system.

And as any IT person knows, backup is just one half of the process, restore is the other. AFAIK, nobody has the slightest clue towards how to manufacture a brain, or even a simulation of a brain sufficiently advanced to allow human consciousness to run.

We are so far away from this that any estimate of when we'll be there is pure speculation.

Comment: Most people are actually able to manufacture a brain that a human consciousness can run on. My parents did it. Yours probably did too.

Comment: "I know how people make more people, but it requires that you have two people to start with, which I hope someone got fired over"  -Glados

Comment: @Michael I know it was a joke, but here's the thing: To manufacture something or to grow something is not the same thing. We might, in fact, be able to grow brains in petri dishes much sooner than building them in factories - but growing something doesn't tell us how, exactly, it works.

Comment: @Tom You are right, but explaining the joke is like dissecting a frog. Of interest only to academics and kills the frog in the process.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd like to mention that exactly this mechanism is used in *Commonwealth Saga* by P.Hamilton. I suggest reading through these books if you'd enjoy seeing how such technology affects society in everyday life. Probably there are dozens of other examples, though.

Now, regarding the question: we are far away from such tech.

1. We don't know how exactly our brain works. Currently, we're able to
   create neural networks with [150+ billions](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/computing/software/biggest-neural-network-ever-pushes-ai-deep-learning) of neurons, and yet
   we're not even close to simulating human brain. As AlexP pointed out below, it's not quite correct to compare artificial neuronetworks (ANN) with human brain because they serve different purpose. But history of such networks begins with modelling human neurons, so let's at least say we *tried* to simulate the brain.
2. We don't know how exactly the information is *stored* inside our brain. In simple words, we think that patterns of active neural chains form our memories, but I haven't heard about anyone ever replicating "memory' as it is. There is also a [holographic theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_brain_theory): we assume that each piece of information is spread all over the brain. If we remove some part of it, we can still restore the entire memory from the rest of the brain at the cost of "resolution". Just like with holographic pictures. Generic information like reflexes might be stored this way. I mean, there are different views on how it works and no one ever claimed their approach to be 100% correct.
3. Even *restoring* memory is almost impossible in case when it's not a
   psychological factor (like intuitive defence mechanism). [Here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3495502/What-memory-LOOKS-like-Scientists-restore-lost-memories-flicking-light-switch-brain.html)
   we see scientists restore part of the memory for mice, but as far as
   I understand it, it doesn't last long after procedure is over. So
   technically, if we want to restore memory via medical intervention,
   we're in trouble.

So, in conclusion, we are not ready to introduce separate memory storage compatible with human brain. Because memories are not binary, I suspect we need to simulate neurons to properly treat them outside of our heads. Of course, that is my personal opinion.

Comment: Also, ZioByte and ths in the comment above made a good point - we don't know how to upload data directly into the brain.

Comment: *"We're able to create neural networks with 150+ billions of neurons":* An actual biological network of actual biological neurons, and an [artificial neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) as used in computing are vastly different things. They are only vaguely similar to each other, in that they are both made up of interconnected simple computing nodes. It is not expected that an artificial neural network will somehow duplicate the operation of a biological brain.

Comment: Agree, though the history of such networks started exactly by trying to replicate neurons. Later, people discovered cons and pros of ANNs, enhanced latter using various techniques and applied all this in different fields like visual object recognition, classification and so on. So yeah, no one expect Alpha Go or Deep Dream to become as smart as human in _everything_.

Comment: AlexP, edited my comment according to your correction.

Comment: A little tip: you need to use an "@" in front of a username to notify them. Only the OP of a post is normally notified of a comment and one person can be notified per comment. It even autocompletes. So to notify Alex of your response you would need to write @AlexP (like I just did) somewhere in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know how far we are away from eternal consciousness.  We are far enough away from being able to do this that we don't even know enough to figure out how far we are away!  Most agree it wont happen soon (i.e. not in the next 25 years), but nobody can say whether we're 100 years away or 100,000,000 years away.

We don't even have a solid scientific definition of consciousness, though there are [some interesting ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory) being floated which rely on information theory.  It's not even clear whether or not the idea of "preserving consciousness" is meaningful without also preserving the entire environment (i.e. copying the universe).

Also unclear is whether one can copy a consciousness without also copying the death-creating features that are present in our cells.  It may not be possible to unlink what we call "consciousness" from the natural cycle of life and death.  The thing that we may unlink from this cycle may not even meet our current definitions for consciousness.

I highly recommend reading about the philosophical problem: [The Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).  It is a thought experiment regarding identity which dates at least 2000 years back, and there is still not a solid consensus as to how to resolve this problem.  We would *certainly* need to have solved this multi-milinia old problem before we could accomplish what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that I haven't seen considered in the existing answers: rather than just "far away", it might be fundamentally impossible.

First, a short anecdote: some time in the 90s I ran a primitive markov bot (perhaps even too primitive to be called a markov bot since it didn't really even have weighted probabilities) on IRC. For readers not familiar with the concept, the general idea was that it would build a corpus of short chains of words from things other people chatting wrote, and randomly assemble them into sometimes-meaningful sentences. Anyway, at initial setup most of the output was nonsense, after a few weeks it was producing lots of amusement, and after a few more weeks the output was again nonsense. The problem was that both presence of "useful associations", and absence of "too many associations", was necessary to get something other than garbage out.

So, back to human or human-like consciousness: it's possible that the entire neural model of our consciousness has fundamental limits on "how much experience" it can accumulate without becoming overloaded and starting to produce less-useful and eventually all-garbage output. If there is such a limit, it might or might not scale with the size of the neural network. This kind of limit seems plausible in terms of how our experience of consciousness changes with age or with accumulation of more and more fields of knowledge, gradually transforming from vivid memories of specific things and events to more of a "digest memory". What happens if you keep throwing more experience into that without bound? Does it break down entirely into dementia? Is dementia entirely a matter of physical/physiological faults in the nervous system, or also partly a computational state? Can a human (or augmented/digitized) mind progress successfully to further and further states of being able to work with thousands or millions of years of experiences?

Fortunately, these are all amazingly fun questions from a scifi writing/worldbuilding perspective, but if anything the fact that they're open supports the view that we're at best far, far away from achieving what OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it is possible but the person can not be put into a computer directly.

In order for eternal life to exist we first must invent sentient Artificial Intelligence. Once sentient A.I is in existence we may be able to programme personality traits into it. Once we have the same personality of whoever wants to be posthumanised we then have to collect their memories. This is simple as we could just have the person in question give their life story in as much detail as possible and all of the knowledge they have acquired. So once we have an A.I programmed with their personality we programme their memories into it. Once the A.I is programmed, and the customer is satisfied, we must then kill the customer. This is to prevent any problems that would be caused by there being two of the same personality. an Android is then built that looks exactly like the person, their digital clone is put into it, and then we send the clone out. Then it lives it's life as the original.

Yes I do know that this idea is not the actual person but it is the closest way I can think of that is realistic. The problem with "cloud saving" memories is that the brain and computers are radically different to each other. If you would like to research this topic further this concept is called whole brain emulation.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR -- I can believe the upload might be possible in the far future, but I don't think download is feasible**

This is difficult, difficult.  Let's say our scanning technology is awesome; we can map every neuron-to-neuron connection and (if necessary) the current charge-state of each.  Cool, we upload Jim to our computer.

Oh dear ... we forgot the epicellular data -- the brain is awash in hormones and chemicals of various sorts.  Okay, with v2 we got this measured and modeled too.  So now we have a copy of ol' Jimbo.  Oh dear ... we forgot that there is a steady stream of *input* coming into the brain from all the nerves.  Computer-Jim quickly goes insane from total sensory deprivation.  Time for v3.

Okay, now we're cool.  Jim and Computer-Jim amuse themselves with endless games of "Jinx!  You owe me a soda!"  Till finally Computer-Jim sobers a bit and says, "So when they restore back into my head, will it hurt?"  Jim goes, "No, **I'm** the one with the body, dummy!"  CJ:  "Nuh-uh."  J:  "Yeah-huh"  CJ and J together:  "Jerk. ... Jinx!  You owe me a soda!"

Here's where it gets **really** hard.  The transfer is not just information; we have to physically wind the neurons into place, adjust the chemical soup of the cerebrospinal fluid, and make sure all the right neurons are firing.  Assuming you've found a volunteer body, or a ... "volunteer" body, this is a tough row to hoe.

But cool.  Restored-Jim *immediately* goes into convulsions.  Oh dear ... could it be that the lower levels of his brain aren't interfacing properly with the signals coming out of the spinal cord?  Restored-Jim's body has different muscle mass.  A different amount of skin.  Might be opposite sex.  The signals coming out from his cerebellum are going to the wrong muscles (including the heart, woops) or using the wrong amount of force.  There might not even *be* a good mapping of spinal-cord nerves to cerebellum nerves.

But let's say we overcome this somehow.  Restored-Jim feels *awful* in his new body.  Nothing works right.  He doesn't fit his own self-image.  "Didn't I used to be caucasian?  Is Turkish really *me*?  Do you have something in an early Aztec physique?"

While watching this, Computer-Jim -- we didn't turn him off, right? -- is saying "This is no fair!  Why did you send *him* to the new body and not *me*?"  Doc: "Uh..."  Computer-Doc: "Jeez you idiot!  Why did I let you have the body this week anyway?"

Comment: I enjoyed your writing (not my DV), but you did not really answer the question. These are the implications of such a technology, it doesn't deal with how far ahead the means are.

Comment: Dear @Guran ... I may have sailed off on a tangent a bit there, I'll admit it.  ;D  That said, the point I was trying to make is that I don't think the "restore" is even possible, unless you have what is essentially full matter-manipulation control down to the atomic level.  The upload seems at least theoretically possible, though I can't really put a timeframe on it.  Even so, I'd love to see a story where the restore *almost* works, and the people get loopier and loopier after every time through the cycle...

Comment: Yeah, there are a number of stories still to be written around this topic. The reason I asked, naturally.